# reinterpret_cast changes type from `const float *` to `float` unexpectedly

Tags: c++, qt, reinterpret-cast

I have a pointer:

```cpp
const float  *m_posBufferPtr_float;
```

I assign to this variable with:

```cpp
m_posBufferPtr_float = reinterpret_cast<const float *>(buffer()->data().constData());
```

At which `constData()` function returns `const char *` type:

```cpp
inline const char *QByteArray::constData() const
{ return d->data(); }
```

Therefore my `reinterpret_cast` *should* convert `const char *` to `const float *`.

---

But to my surprise, exactly **before** `reinterpret_cast` my pointer is:

[image: Before]

and exactly **after** `reinterpret_cast` debugger shows my pointer as:

[image: After]

---

I wonder why `reinterpret_cast` is converting `const char *` to `float` rather than `const float *`

Comment: The debugger seems to display the pointed value and not its address. If you check the type, it's `float` in the second image and `float*` in the first one.

Comment: You could confirm the above by creating a simple toy program that just assigns a const float ptr to the address of a const float.

Comment: @RomhaKorev Thanks. On images, the three columns are `Name`, `Value` and `Type`. The value on images is in red color.

Comment: It's not converting it  I would assume it's just your debugger trying to be helpful and dereferencing the pointer to show you the pointed-to value instead of the value of the pointer.

Comment: Please try to create a [mcve] to show us.

Comment: @user3405291, I noticed that. But, the type is not the same (`float*` becoming `float`). I suppose your debugger interprets the pointer for you and displays the pointed value.

Comment: I tried it too, works fine here. Cout is printing the pointer address, when I try to print the float pointer. Using gcc-7 and looked in vscode debugger, where everything was fine.

Comment: `reinterpret_cast` does not convert anything. As the name says it causes your program to **reinterpret** a char pointer as a float pointer. If your char pointer is not pointing at a float you have problems.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you take this snippet:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    float* pointer = nullptr;

    float value = 12.34;
    pointer = &value;


    qDebug() << *pointer;
}
```

and execute it step by step, you will see in your debugger:

[image]

Then

[image]

Notice that the type became `float` when the pointer has been initialized. It's due to the configuration of the debugger.

In Qt Creator, right-click on your pointer and uncheck *Dereference pointers automatically*:

[image]